# YII2 advanced with PGSQL

Tags: postgresql, yii2, php-pgsql

[image]

I am facing this type of error while try to login on live server. Locally everything working fine...

Anyone, please help me... Thank you in advance...

Comment: You mean same server or two different servers?

Comment: two different server. 1) code server 2) database server

Comment: Locally means in localhost in my computer and another is live server with centOS and pgsql server

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand

Comment: I don't know about that because I don't know how to check postgre version on live server with command line

Comment: Local version: 9.4 and live version is 8.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`string_agg` became available on postgres +9.0

compare **Aggregate Functions** documentation

**[8.4](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/functions-aggregate.html)** vs **[9.0](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/functions-aggregate.html)**

Comment: Thank you. I understand the concern. It's a version problem.